# How to load Images via Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have to import a lot of Images into my website that are all basically the same.
And i dont want to copy and paste over and over again code like this:

```
<img id="example1" src="example.png" />
<img id="example2" src="example.png" />
```

So is there a way to load these Images in my website/HTML with a for loop or something in Javascript?

Comment: Semi-related; if you have a lot of things that are "basically the same", you might want to consider using _class_ attributes rather than _id_ attributes.

Comment: Yes, it is very possible.

Comment: well the images are the same, but i need different positions so yeah ids.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener("load", picture);
function picture()
{
  var pictures = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  for(var i =0; i<pictures.length; i++)
  {
   pictures[i].setAttribute("src", "example"+i+".jpg");
  }
}
```

Understand that this will get every img tag and increment the src for you. The file names will need to be in increments as well. No real easy way to do it programmatically without php or some language that can read folder contents.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would probably be to use the `Image()` constructor to create the images and then append them one by one.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "http://placehold.it/100x100.png";

  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just have them in a particular order:

```
imagesNumbered(prefix,extension,num) {
    var images = [];
    for(var i=0;i<num;i++) {
        images[i] = new Image();
        images[i].src = prefix+i+extension;
        images[i].alt = prefix+i+extension;
    }
    return images;
}

// returns img/pic0.jpg ... img/pic9.jpg
var imgs = imagesNumbered('img/pic','.jpg',10);
```

Or if you need to explicitly name them:

```
imagesNamed(path,names) {
    var images = [];
    for(var i=0,l=names.length;i<l;i++) {
        images[i] = new Image();
        images[i].src = path+names[i];
        images[i].alt = path+names[i];
    }
    return images;
}

// returns img/foo.jpg, img/bar.png
var names = ['foo.jpg','bar.png'];
var imgs = imagesNamed('img/',names);
```

Whichever one you use, you get an array. Here we append them to an element with an ID of container:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
for(var i=0,l=imgs.length;i<l;i++)
    { container.appendChild(imgs[i]); }
```

Note that I also set the alt attribute, so if for some reason an image fails to load, you can track down the issue more quickly.